# Gateway between wireless network and wired network not routing packets

Tags: linux, iptables, routing

I have the following interfaces/routes :

```
# ip route show
192.168.101.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.101.10
192.168.8.0/24 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.8.1
default via 192.168.101.251 dev eth0
```

Device eth0 is connected to a network with a gateway (192.168.101.251).

My clients are behind an access point (with some hotspot software) which is connected to tun0:

```
clients -> tun0 -> gateway -> eth0 -> internet
```

I can ping an internet host from eth0 but my clients behind the hotspot can't access internet through tun0.
How do I route packets from tun0 to internet (and back) ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable ip_forward on the gateway:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

and masquerade your clients:

```
# /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
# /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

You also need to set your clients to use the IP of tun0 as their default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You must route default gateway for `0.0.0.0` to `tun0`

For example:

```
route add -net default gw 192.168.101.251 dev tun0
```

might works for you. May be you have to remove default GW for eth0

```
route del -net default gw 192.168.101.251 dev eth0
```

This will routes all internet traffic over `tun0` device.
If you add these two lines in to end of /etc/network/interfaces file, it runs on system boot..

Comment: But if I do this I will not be able to connect to internet from eth0. I want to be able to connect from both interfaces.

Comment: Basically you can not do a request same time with both connection. You can do load balancing when one connection is occupied by a request(s), system tries other one. But I have no knowledge about load balancing..

Comment: Not both interfaces are connected to internet, just eth0, tun0 is being configured to act as a captive portal and thus requests from there should be routed through eth0 and back. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Are you saying you want to make the internet on eth0 available to whatever is connected on the other side of tun0?

Comment: Yes Tim that's exactly what I need.